# ContextErrorException: Undefined Index when using composite key for doctrine associations with Symfony 3 entities

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, composite-primary-key

I have two entities where each <kbd>Product</kbd> can have oneToMany <kbd>Aspect</kbd> entities associated to it.

As the Products table is very large I am using `bigint` for it's ID, and consequently, I am trying to build a composite key for <kbd>Aspect</kbd> to use Product ID and a `smallint` (which I am trying to increment with `Product#aspectsCount`). However, I am getting a ContextErrorException:

> Notice: Undefined index: aspect

My entities are as below (I originally tried `indexBy="id")` in the hope of using <kbd>Aspect</kbd>'s numeric ID but I can't seem to get that working either so used `name` below to be more consistent with examples I've read online):

### Product Entity

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint", options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Aspect", mappedBy="product", cascade={"all"}, indexBy="name")
     */
    private $aspects;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="aspectsCount", type="smallint", options={"unsigned"=true}, nullable=false)
     */
    private $aspectsCount;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->aspects = new ArrayCollection();

        $this->setCreateDT(new \Datetime);
        $this->setUpdateDT(new \Datetime);
        $this->aspectsCount = 0;
    }


    /**
     * Add aspect
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Aspect $aspect
     *
     * @return product
     */
    public function addAspect($name)
    {
        $aspect = new Aspect($this, $name);
        $this->aspects[$name] = $aspect;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove aspect
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Aspect $aspect
     */
    public function removeAspect(\AppBundle\Entity\Aspect $aspect)
    {
        $this->aspects->removeElement($aspect);
        $this->setAspectsCount($this->aspectsCount-1);
    }
}
```

### Aspect Entity

```
class Aspect
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="aspects") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", options={"unsigned"=true}, nullable=false)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="text")
     */
    private $name;

    public function __construct($product, $name)
    {
        $product->setAspectsCount($product->getAspectsCount()+1);

        $this->product = $product;
        $this->id = $product->getAspectsCount();
        $this->name = $name;
    }

 }
```

By extension, if another table should exist "underneath" <kbd>Aspect</kbd>, how would such an association be made? Would Doctrine handle the composite key internally or would I need to do something such as:

```
class Aspect_subtype
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product")   
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Aspect")    
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="aspect_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $aspect;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", options={"unsigned"=true}, nullable=false)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="text")
     */
    private $name;

// etc...
}
```

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: aspect` where is that error

Comment: I am using FOSRestBundle and this error gets returned in JSON when I request a route that uses the Product entity

Comment: Are they your complete entities? if not post them as well 
And post your FOSBundle code for insertion as well. I may learn something new as well

Comment: because i see `$this->setCreateDT(new \Datetime);
        $this->setUpdateDT(new \Datetime);`
and ` $product->setAspectsCount($product->getAspectsCount()+1);` but they are not defined anywhere

Comment: I'm 'unfortunately' on vacation so can't get the full code to post - but this is the boiled down code which is giving me the problem. The `getAspectsCount()+1` (and related) code you mention is used to store a counter in each Product   just so each new Aspect for an Item has an incremented integer for the ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in product Entity change the anotations of $Aspets to this

```
     /**
     *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Aspect")
     *@ORM\JoinColumn(name="Client", referencedColumnName="product_id",onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $aspects;
```

Then you need to update your database schema

Comment: I fat-finger flagged this answer instead of awarding my bounty(!). I can't raise a flag to admin now as I have already (accidentally) flagged it. Thank you for solving the problem. Can an admin please fix (and delete this comment if possible)?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem occurs when you do $this->aspects[$name] = $aspect;
It is an ArrayCollection, not an array and even though in most cases it works like one, you cannot set a name for an item in the collection. Besides ArrayCollections are more complex objects and also allow querying and ordering them. Simply call $this->aspects->add($aspect);

As per your last question, you can define multiple join columns, when specifying a manyToOne relationship, so you would just add definitions for multiple columns, instead of one in the case, you needed to relate to an entity which has a composite key.

Lastly, I would like to note one thing form my personal experience: many features, that are built into programming languages and programs as well, often add unnecessary complexity to the software you are writing. If you have the ability (and most of the time you do) you should shy away from things like composite keys/inheritance/etc... . Often times they prove to provide no real benefit, yet might become a nightmare to work with in the future. There are cases when you cannot do without them, but those are few and far between.

In your case you are already wasting time contemplating how would this composite key thingy work when you need to add relations (also composite keys are a bit less performant when it comes to querying) yet even if you didn't use the composite key (just the regular id on the aspect entity instead), calling the getAspects() method would still provide you with an arraycollection that is ordered by ID(by default. this can be changed), so you would still be able to number the items and the ordering will stay the same. Even if you had to implement something like ability for users to change the order of elements, you could still simply add another order field to the entity, and not spend a second thinking how composite key here is going to interact with the rest of the system. And again, these problems do not disappear, just because you find solutions now, they will also add to the complexity of the program in the future too.

Comment: Thank you - very good point. The other answer fixed my immediate problem but I am going to step back and reconsider the composite keys as you suggested